# Tracking php process on framework

Tags: php, linux, debugging, process

I have a php framework is running on linux machine basicly every requests redirect to index.php by .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*jpg$|!.*gif$|!.*png$|!.*jpeg$|!.*bmp$


RewriteRule . index.php
```

One of my php started to run %100 CPU i want to track which progress is that but when i check process with

ps aux | grep 23791

```
user 23791  0.3  0.8  30460 15288 ?        S    12:32   0:01 /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/index.php
```

As normal, request redirect to index.php.But i have to find which request is this.

Is there any way to debug this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find my own question while im searcing for this issue. This time i have an answer.

If you want to see details of your progress on linux console via ps you have to use [proctitle](https://pecl.php.net/package/proctitle) this pecl extension will give you

[setproctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php)() function.

extension is very old but still working even zts mode.

If you are using cli version you can use : [cli-set-process-title()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.cli-set-process-title.php) this is native php function (version PHP5 >=)

So simple code that i use to track on linux :

```
<?
if ((PHP_SAPI === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN'))) {
    $tmp = $_SERVER["argv"];
    unset($tmp[0]);
    $text =  "/". implode('/',$tmp);
    @cli_set_process_title (urldecode($text));
} else {
    @setproctitle (urldecode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
}
?>
```

I just write this to top index.php on codeigniter.

For see processes uses most cpu and memory at linux :

```
ps o pid,stat,time,pcpu,pmem,cmd -C php --sort -pcpu
```

now you will able to see processes

Answer (score 1):

you can use firephp or log for append to a file on linux do you want some pointers  or is that enough info ?

Comment: Thanks for answer but my most of processes are running via cron there is no frond ends. Adding append to log is not a option i guess, project about million line, if i dont have a track i cant add logging to all progress.